# How do I create relationship from json column data on same table?

Tags: php, eloquent, json-api

I have something like the following table (tablename = `applications`):

```
| id            | applicants    |  
| ------------- | ------------- | 
| uuid-123-abc  | [{'first_name':'Dave'},{'first_name':'Steve'}] |
```

I need to be able to create a relationship for it so I can just go:

`$application->applicants` and (in this example) get a collection with two `Applicant` models.

I'm assuming I'll need an Applicant model class somewhere. But I'm not even sure if this can be done because there is no `applicant` table.

I was trying just:

```
public function applicants()
{
    return Collection::make([$this->applicants]);
```

But that's not a relationship and I'm trying to get this to work with [Neromerx JsonApi](https://github.com/neomerx/json-api).

In fact, if there is a way to imitate this behaviour for JsonApi I'd just as happily use that solution.

So far my relationships have all been pretty straight forward. And I'd like to be able to get the applicants in the same way:

```
use Neomerx\JsonApi\Schema\SchemaProvider;

class ApplicationSchema extends SchemaProvider
{
    protected $resourceType = 'applications';

    public function getId($application) {
        return $application->id;
    }

    public function getAttributes($application) {
        return [
            .....
        ];
    }

    public function getRelationships($application, $isPrimary, array $includeRelationships) {
        return [
            'applicants' => [self::DATA => $application->applicants];
        ];
    }
}
```

Can it be done using one of these approaches?

I'm not using Laravel I'm just using Eloquent (version 5.5) on it's own in Slim.

Comment: What features should this "relationship" have? Do you just want to get a collection of `Applicant` instances from the JSON string?

Comment: That should be all that's required, yes. And it should be available within the "relationships" scope on an Eloquent model.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the last sentence?

Comment: Eloquent models have a "relations" attribute which will contain all existing (and if requested) related data. [Here be the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#introduction)

Comment: Why is it important to use the `$relations` property in your case?

Comment: It's the convention when using Neomerx JsonApi with Eloquent. That any relationships will have it's own Model and that that model will be accessible via the getRelationships method. I can't work out how it works though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170293/discussion-between-mikelovelyuk-and-jonas-staudenmeir).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
public function getApplicantsAttribute()
{
    $items = json_decode($this->attributes['applicants']);
    $instance = new Applicant();
    return $instance->newCollection(array_map(function($item) use($instance) {
        return $instance->newFromBuilder($item);
    }, $items));
}
```

Comment: But I still won't be able to load it as a relationship through the Application model. Eg `$application->applicants`

Comment: You can, if you rename the method to `getApplicantsAttribute` and replace `$this->applicants` with `$this->attributes['applicants']`.