# One To Many Relationship in Eloquent with JSON field

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a connection between a JSON field in my database and a table which stores music by ID. So, I have a table called "playlists" which has a field called "songs". In this "songs" field I have a `array[]` of song ID's e.g. `[1,2]`. I tried the following code to make a relationship between these two tables:

```
class Playlist extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'playlists';

    public function songs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Music', 'id');
    }

}
```

I used the `foreign_key` **id**  because of the **songs** table which has a **id** field.

The code I used to retrieve the **playlist** from the controller is as follows:

```
$playlist = Playlist::find($id)->songs;
print_r($playlist);
```

Which outputs:
`[1,2]`

I most probably did something wrong, not understanding the relationships correctly. Could someone explain how this works? I looked up the documentation but did not get any wiser.

Comment: Are you using Postgres?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Nope, using MySQL

Comment: Have you seen this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50140271/how-do-i-create-relationship-from-json-column-data-on-same-table ?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Looks like they're trying to get it to work on the same table which is not something I need. Also, there must be a easier way, a more "Laravel way" to do this, I suppose?

Comment: But you probably should transform that text/json field into a separate table. Try writing that join yourself manually. You'll find out it's not really possible through SQL alone (at least not with MySQL, which is why I asked about Postgres which has a native JSON data type on which you can query and index).

Comment: Try renaming `songs()` function name to something else & call it. Doubting there may be confusion between `songs` attribute name & function name. If the relationship between Playlist & Music is many-to-many try creating a pivot table & map. You can find tutorial on many-to-many in online

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam Right, when I rename the function and call it, it shows the correct data! Now the hard part, how do I get it to show as the `songs` field? So, how do I merge it into the `find()` results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the really good solution for keeping data in column on json format. It help me on previous project online shop

https://scotch.io/tutorials/working-with-json-in-mysql

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this!

Comment: you are welcome man. It help me previous. I am glad that it will help to you!!

Comment: link not working

Answer (score 6):

Laravel has no native support for JSON relationships.

I created a package for this: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations

If you rename the `songs` column to `song_ids`, you can define a many-to-many relationship like this:

```
class Playlist extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

    protected $casts = [
       'song_ids' => 'json',
    ];

    public function songs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToJson('App\Music', 'song_ids');
    }
}

class Music extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

    public function playlists()
    {
       return $this->hasManyJson('App\Playlist', 'song_ids');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a brilliant package.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is a very old post but I will go ahead and drop my own opinion for my future self and fellow googlers.....

So, If I got this question correctly, you are trying to use a JSON field for a relationship query. This issue I have stumbled across a couple of times, at different occasions for different use-cases. With the most recent being for the purpose of saving a couple of Ids belonging to different tables, in a single JSON field on a given table (While I keep pondering on why the Laravel guy won't just add this functionality already! I Know Pivots, Data Normalization etc....But I'm pleading for the 1%). Until I came across this post on [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/create-a-custom-relationship-method) that worked like a charm.

Apologies for the long intro, let me get right into it....

On your Playlist model (in Laravel 8.0 and a few older versions I can't really keep track of) you can do something like so;

```
public function songs() 
{
    $related = $this->hasMany(Song::class);
    $related->setQuery(
        Song::whereIn('id', $this->song_ids)->getQuery()
    );

    return $related;
}
```

Comment: I noticed after testing this method that it does indeed work when querying the relationship without eager loading, but does not work with eager loading (ie. the `->with('songs')` method). The reason for this seems to be that since the query is combined, the `$this->song_ids` is null in the relationship’s method.